# how to hide text inside a PNG or JPEG file

Tags: python, image, text

I'm trying to hide text inside an image using a python script,
I've found the library "Stegano", but when I'm trying to use the "hide" function
on PNG file the function asks if I want to convert the PNG file to RGB mode (y/n)

how can make the program send y that when the function asks this the program will immediately send y for yes...

any ideas?

Comment: It depends what operating system you use and how you run the program.

Comment: how to do it for windows?

Comment: `import os`
`os.system('pip uninstall pandas')`
I'm trying out the above, it is strucking in confirmation. How can i respond 'y' through script?

Comment: @Gokulnath If you have a question, please ask in the normal way, not in the comments to a different question... `pip uninstall -y pandas`